# Why is my variant showing as VT_EMPTY despite containing a safearray

Tags: c++, vba, com, ole, safearray

I am trying to return an array which is a portion of a vector to VBA. The vector is just an array of data from a test file stored as an std::string. I would like to pass a Row variable to the DLL and have this return the given data from that line down to that line + 1000. The issue is that the return variant is just showing as VT_EMPTY in VBA. Can anyone help, I am quite new to C++ in general, and haven't got much COM experience.

```
LONG __stdcall BDH::GetRange(const uint32_t& Row, const uint32_t& Column, VARIANT* pDest)
{
    // Validate row
    if (!(Row - 1 > 0))
        return -1;
    
    // Validate column
    if (!(Column - 1 > 0))
        return -1;

    // Check row isn't biggest than the last index
    if (Row - 1 > SourceData.size())
        return -1;

    // Check column isn't biggest than the last index of the first element
    if (Column - 1 > SourceData[0].size())
        return -1;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Initialise the return variant and set the vartype to variant array
    VariantInit(pDest);
    pDest->vt = VT_VARIANT | VT_ARRAY;

    // Create safearray and bound object
    SAFEARRAYBOUND Bound[2];

    Bound[0].lLbound = 1; // Array starting at 1 (VBA style)

    // Decide whether the size should be 1000 or the difference between row and size
    if ((SourceData.size() - Row) < 1000)
        Bound[0].cElements = SourceData.size() - Row;
    else
        Bound[0].cElements = 1000;

    Bound[1].lLbound = 1; // Start at 1
    Bound[1].cElements = SourceData[0].size(); // Set the second dimension size

    pDest->parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, Bound); // Create the safearray within the variant 

    // Iterators and array indices data
    uint32_t i, j;
    LONG Indices[2];

    for (uint32_t i = Row - 1; i < Row - 1 + 1000; i++)
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < SourceData[i].size() - 1; j++)
        {
            // Set the index
            Indices[0] = i;
            Indices[1] = j;

            // Create the variant
            VARIANT Element;
            VariantInit(&Element);
            Element.vt = VT_BSTR;
            
            // Set the string value (use SysAllocStringByteLen to reduce space - string is ANSI)
            Element.bstrVal = SysAllocStringByteLen(SourceData[i][j].c_str(), SourceData[i][j].size());

            // Add the element to the safearray
            SafeArrayPutElement(pDest->parray, Indices, &Element);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Example of wrapper for this function

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall ExampleWrapper(LONG x, LONG y, VARIANT* pDest)
{
    BDH bdh;
    bdh.GetRange((uint32_t)x, (uint32_t)y, pDest);
}
```

Comment: How do you declare the VBA side? is it a COM interface or a DLL export?

Comment: Why are you calling CoInitialize()? It doesn't belong in this code. It is the responsibility of the caller to initialize COM beforehand.

Comment: Also, `Row` and `Column` are **unsigned** types, so think real hard about what `Row - 1` and `Column - 1` return if the caller passes in 0 for them.

Comment: Also, `SysAllocStringByteLen()` stores raw bytes in a `BSTR`, but VBA will be expecting actual Unicode strings. Use `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `SysAllocString()` instead.

Comment: @SimonMourier DLL Export

Comment: @RemyLebeau Will this misuse of `SysAllocStringByteLen` cause the issue though? I replaced this with a `SysAllocString(L"Hello World")` to test and the variant was still showing as empty in the VBA debug Window.

Comment: How do you declare the VBA side

Comment: VBA side is fine, first test I did was to set the BSTR value of the variant... that worked fine, its only when I added the safearray stuff it started showing the variant as empty. `Private Declare PtrSafe Sub TestGetRange Lib "example.dll" (ByVal x as Long, ByVal y as Long, ByRef pDest as Variant)` - Bare in mind that that I have a wrapper for this function @SimonMourier

Comment: If you're sure everything is fine, don't ask for help . What is SourceData? What is CoInitialize doing here? where is error handling? etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Wrightmare the VBA declaration is all wrong. The DLL side returns a `LONG` but the VBA side says `Sub` (no return value). More importantly, on the DLL side, the `Row` and `Column` parameters are taken by reference, but on the VBA side they are passed by value. Your DLL code does not initialize the `VARIANT` when returning `-1` on an input error. Which implies the VBA side is initializing the `VARIANT` before calling the DLL, and then the DLL is not overwriting it due to an input error. Which makes sense when mismatching value and reference semantics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau " Bare in mind that that I have a wrapper for this function" - The code above is not being called directly, there is a wrapper function in between - It would not work as the Row and Column params are being passed by reference.

Comment: @Wrightmare it would help if you would also show the actual wrapper that VBA is directly calling.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added the wrapper

Comment: @Wrightmare I strongly suggest you fix your `Row`/`Column` usage in `BDH::GetRange()`, you are mixing 0-based, 1-based, and even 2-based index logic. Which base are you actually expecting the caller to use? Also, since `LONG` is signed but `uint32_t` is unsigned, you should add some additional range checks in `ExampleWrapper()` before calling `BDH::GetRange()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But this doesn't answer my question - the question is why is the return variant showing as empty rather than containing an array. I am passing 1000 and 1000 as the row and column parameters, so in this case those parameters won't throw an exception.

Comment: @Wrightmare I already addressed that in an earlier comment: "*Your DLL code does not initialize the VARIANT when returning -1 on an input error. Which implies the VBA side is initializing the VARIANT before calling the DLL, and then the DLL is not overwriting it due to an input error.*" What does your `SourceData` actually contain? Maybe it doesn't contain 1000 rows/columns to begin with? You really need to actually debug your code to see what is *really* happening, stop guessing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau variant isn't initialized on the VBA side. If I do a test by adding a BSTR value to the same variant, this can be seen on the VBA side. SourceData is like 100,000 lines long - If I was referring to an index that didn't exist I would get a seg fault anyway.

Comment: @RemyLebeau of course its not going to be initialized if a -1 is returned, but a -1 is never returned!

Comment: @Wrightmare [VBA *DOES* initialize a `VARIANT` to Empty when declared](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/variant-empty.htm). You have no way yo *prove* what you claim since you are not debugging your code, or at least returning the `LONG` result of `GetRange()` to VBA to know if it actually returned -1 or 0. Change the return value of `ExampleWrapper()`, add some output debug mesaages to your DLL, do *something* to validate your DLL is actually attempting to set the `VARIANT` to an array. So far, everything I've seen suggests that it is to NOT doing so, but you have not PROVED it yet

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have attached the debugger, set a break point at the end of the function, before it returns 0. Again, it does not return -1!

Comment: @Wrightmare If you can see (in the debugger) that your DLL is actually setting `pDest->vt = VT_VARIANT | VT_ARRAY;` and yet the `Variant` on the VBA side remains `Empty` after the DLL exits, then that would obviously mean `pDest` is NOT pointing directly at your VBA `Variant` but to some other `Variant`. Upon initial entry to `GetRange()`, what is `pDest->vt` actually set to? Is it `VT_EMPTY` (expected), or is it maybe something more like `VT_VARIANT | VT_BYREF`? Is the memory address that is stored in `pDest` match the same address reported by `VarPtr(YourVariantVariable)` on the VBA side?